# Install guest CentOS 7 on KVM also on CentOS7 without GUI

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos7, console, virsh

I'm a bit stuck with virtualization on CentOS 7 using KVM. Whenever I try to create a virtual machine it keeps telling me to connect to the machine via console and finish the installation. Whenever I connect, I can't enter enything, I can only escape from the console.

The way I create the machine:

> virt-install --name vm1 --network bridge:br0 --ram=1024 --vcpus=1
>   --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/imagesw.img,size=10 --graphics none --location=/mnt/iso

The machine is running, at least that is what

> virsh list --all

telling me. How can I finish the installation and begin to use the guest OS from within the server? I have no GUI to access it, I use only terminal.

Thank you in advance!

B.R.: Bert

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is either a boot system that is not configured with serial console settings, or a VM that does not have a serial device added to it. In most cases, you will have to modify your installer boot options (specifically, kernel arguments) to include something along the lines of `console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200`. Also be sure that you have included a serial device in your virt-install line, as I do not see one added. I expound on this later in my answer.

You could use something altogether better suited to this whole task and use `virt-builder`. This creates virtual machine disk images with fairly generic acceptable defaults in a minimal installation. It's a highly customizable tool, just as `virt-install` is. Its man page is tremendously well-written.

`virt-builder` will grab signed virtual machine images from a few dedicated repositories and build a disk image file with those contents (disk image format depending on options chosen). For example, this following command will create a CentOS 7 disk image in qcow2 format, thinly allocated to 20GiB. It will also inject my public ssh key into root's home directory, as well as set the hostname to `fubar`. Give the man page a good read, as the options go far beyond this.

`# virt-builder centos-7 --arch amd64 -o /var/lib/libvirt/images/centos-7.qcow2 --format qcow2 --size 20G --hostname fubar --ssh-inject root:file:~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

This disk image is ready to connect to a VM, which can be done using `virt-install`, almost identically to the way you have done it in your question. There will be one big difference, in that we will specify `--import` alongside `--disk` so that we point to an existing image rather than make a new one. We also won't be specifying "size" within `--disk`, as `--import` excludes that option. Also note that I explicitly added a `--serial` option, as we need to make sure that device exists to get a console on.

`# virt-install --name vm1 --network bridge=br0 --ram=1024 --vcpus=1 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/vm1.qcow2 --import --nographics --serial=pty --os-type=linux --os-variant rhel7`

This will start the "installer" which in this case is just starting the newly provisioned VM and connecting to its serial console.

Comment: Thanks, never heard of virt-builder. Sounds handy, but in my situation it is not useable I think. I need to work in a completly offline environment, thos I can't pull any image from the web.

Actually I've succeeded (sort of) with the follwoing command:
`virt-install --name=firewall --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/firewall.img --ram=1024 --vcpus=1 --network bridge:br0 --nographics --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel7.1 --location /var/lib/libvirt/images/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1609-99.iso --extra-args console=ttyS0`

Now the OS installs, but then it is just standing and can'T do anything in it

Comment: You need more kernel arguments. Specifically, you have to specify consoles on both tty0 and ttyS0, as well as specifying baud rate. As in: `--extra-args console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 rd_NO_PLYMOUTH`.